# What's the best, most concise word for the abbreviations put after one's name to denote the achievement of degrees?

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes

Such as M.d., RN, LSW....

I'm looking for the word that fills the blank in following sentence:

> It is as if living with her for as long as he did merits the addition of a ________ to his signatory.

Comment: *ego-enhancers*

Comment: I'd refer to it as "an AAB"—an Abbreviated Advanced Degree.

Answer (score 2):

The term is *[post-nominal letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters)*.  It is also referred to as *post-nominal abbreviations*, or *post-nominal titles*.  In your sentence, I would probably use *post-nominal title*.

Comment: +1 I have also heard *post-nominal initials*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the term *credentials* in your sentence.

*It is as if living with her for as long as he did merits the addition of credentials to his signatory.*

The Free Dictionary defines [credentials](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/credential) as:

> Evidence or testimonials concerning one's right to credit, confidence, or authority
>
> A letter or certificate giving evidence of the bearer's identity or competence
>
> Anything that provides the basis for confidence, belief, etc., or for extending credit

Answer (score 0):

"academic letters" sounds better than "post nominal" for reasons of redundancy and pretentiousness.

Comment: They are not always academic, however; neither LSW nor RN indicates any particular diploma. There are numerous designations for professional and vocational certifications, licensures, registrations, and memberships, as well as military and religious affiliations, orders, and decorations.

Comment: @choster Known as "credentials." :)

Comment: @JLG There are no credentials in *Rev. Msgr. John R. Doe, S.J.* or *Cdr. Janet A. Doe, USN*.

Comment: I beg to differ. Those are all credentials. See these articles: http://ansjournalblog.com/2011/06/29/how-to-list-your-credentials-and-title-when-you-publish/  http://communications.med.nyu.edu/advertising-branding/editorial-style-guide/academic-degrees-licenses-credentials  http://careersdonewrite.com/blog/resume-help-the-abcs-of-credentials-on-your-resume.html